# Problems with SQL, Arel and filtering out records. Rails. Could use some advice

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I suck so bad at SQL and Arel. I don't even know what Arel is or how to use it. Is there a good resource on this?

I have a an issue that I don't know why it took me so long. Perhaps people can point out why this takes me so long to do.

Anyway, I have a `Products` table and a `Restrictions` table. A product can have many restrictions. A restriction is a US state. Most of my products have no restrictions, but one of my products has a restriction (it cannot be sold in "CT" because "CT" has insane laws).

I want to return back all products that don't have a restriction in CT. However, this query did not work:

`Product.joins(:restrictions).where.not(restrictions: { name: "CT" }).count`

So I was expecting that to return all my products except for the ones product with a restriction to CT. However, it returns nothing:

```
 Product.last.restrictions
  Product Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products"  ORDER BY "products"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
  Restriction Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "restrictions".* FROM "restrictions" INNER JOIN "product_restrictions" ON "restrictions"."id" = "product_restrictions"."restriction_id" WHERE "product_restrictions"."product_id" = $1  [["product_id", 2559]]
[
  #<Restriction:0x007ff0f1dfec58> {
            :id => 11,
      :category => "US State",
          :name => "CT",
    :created_at => Wed, 07 Jun 2017 17:57:42 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Wed, 07 Jun 2017 17:57:42 UTC +00:00
  }
]
[48] pry(main)> Product.count
   (0.6ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products"
2494
[49] pry(main)> Product.joins(:restrictions).where.not(restrictions: { name: "AZ" }).count
   (47.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" INNER JOIN "product_restrictions" ON "product_restrictions"."product_id" = "products"."id" INNER JOIN "restrictions" ON "restrictions"."id" = "product_restrictions"."restriction_id" WHERE ("restrictions"."name" != $1)  [["name", "AZ"]]
1
[50] pry(main)> Product.joins(:restrictions).where.not(restrictions: { name: "CT" }).count
   (6.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" INNER JOIN "product_restrictions" ON "product_restrictions"."product_id" = "products"."id" INNER JOIN "restrictions" ON "restrictions"."id" = "product_restrictions"."restriction_id" WHERE ("restrictions"."name" != $1)  [["name", "CT"]]
0
```

I expected the last query to return 2493 (only that last product has a restriction), not 0. I expected the AZ query to return 2494, not 0.

However, this hood sql works (using NOT EXISTS):

```
state = "CT"
Product.where('NOT EXISTS ' \
    '(SELECT 1 from restrictions
        JOIN product_restrictions
          on product_id = products.id
        WHERE restrictions.name = ? AND restrictions.category = ?)', state, 'US State'
    )
  }
```

The aboe query returns back all products EXCEPT for the one with the restriction in CT

**Questions**

1. Why does my first query using joins not work?
2. How do I get better here? Is there a good book on sql?
3. Is there a better way to write my solution not using like SQL strings?

Answer (score 0):

When you do an INNER JOIN, it creates a join table where it will have entries only for product with associated restrictions. "products without restriction" or "restriction without product_id" will not be included in that.

In the question you mention that "only that last product has a restriction". So when you did a JOIN, it created only 1 entry in the join table, and you got rid of that when you further added the condition on restriction's name. Hence final result is empty.

If you want to include products in the join table even if they do not have a associated restriction, use LEFT OUTER JOIN.
Here is a useful link - [Inner Join vs Left Outer Join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Solution: 
if using rails5:-

```
Product.left_outer_joins(:restrictions).where.not(restrictions: { name: "CT" }).count
```

else

```
Product.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN restrictions on restrictions.product_id = products.id").where.not(restrictions: { name: "CT" }).count
```

Comment: What about rails 4?

Comment: else is for all rails version < 5 . Product.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN restrictions on restrictions.product_id = products.id")